# Understanding arcface, sphereface, and their differences

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, image-recognition

I'm a beginner in ml and I want to make a facial recognition system. While going through the research paper I realized that I'm losing the intuitive sense of the computations. I'm not from a statistical background but till now I can understand logits, cosine similarity, softmax functions.

Can someone please help me to get the core understanding of the computations that are taking place?

How/Why they utilized the weights of the last layer and input feature vectors.

How L2 normalization of the vectors help? Why the margin loss has to be in the range 0 to pi?

In general why softmax is paired with cross entropy loss?

I also read that arcface is much better than any other method including sphereface.

Can someone please formulate the difference?